# How to use Callout in TimelinePlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, labeling

I'd like to annotate a datapoint in my TimelinePlot with a callout. Is there a way or a hack that anyone knows of to get this to work?

```
TimelinePlot[{Callout[Now,"now"],Callout[Now+Quantity[1,"Days"],"later"]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

a hack:

```
DateListPlot[{Callout[{Now, 1}, "now"], Callout[{Now + Quantity[1, "Days"], 1}, "later"]}, 
 Joined -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/10, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DateListPlot[{Callout[{Now, 1}, "now"],  Callout[{Now + Quantity[1, "Days"], 1}, "later"]},
 Joined -> True,  AspectRatio -> 1/10, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]